# Generating a test certification

Tags: unit-test, certificates

Is there a way to generate a certificate that denotes a class has passed its tests so that the class doesn't need to be tested again unless it is changed?

Comment: I believe no. And there are couple of reasons why not -- at at least, what if dependencies (methods, referenced in current class) has been changed?

Answer (score 0):

The closest thing to what you're describing is the feature to only run specified tests as part of a deployment.

This was introduced in Summer '15 ([here are the release notes on it](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer15/release-notes/rn_deployment_run_subset_of_tests.htm)), and can potentially work on anything that uses the Metadata API (like the Force.com Migration Tool). I also know that the option to run specific tests is given when you use a Change Set to deploy between orgs ([since Winter '16](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter16/release-notes/rn_deployment_change_sets_test_levels.htm)).

I'm not entirely sure how this interacts with the rule requiring 75% overall coverage of Apex/Triggers (though if each deployment is required to have at least 75% coverage, if you were to eventually deploy all your code, you're guaranteed to have at least 75% coverage overall).

The documentation on [Running a Subset of Tests in a Deployment](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.daas.meta/daas/forcemigrationtool_deploy_run_specific_tests.htm) (documentation for the Force.com Migration Tool) also contains some guidance here:

> If the code coverage of an Apex component in the deployment is less than 75%, the deployment fails. If one of the specified tests fails, the deployment also fails. We recommend that you test your deployment in sandbox first to ensure that the specified tests cover each component sufficiently. Even if your organization’s overall code coverage is 75% or more, the individual coverage of the Apex components being deployed can be less. If the code coverage requirement isn’t met, write more tests and include them in the deployment.